# Grant Create/Alter/Drop Function/Procedure, not Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm looking to create a database role within a database that allows the developer members of that role the ability to create/alter/drop procedures and functions.  I do not want them to be able to create/alter/drop tables though, that is managed by a different team.

I found `GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE/TABLE/FUNCTION`, but I'm not able to allow them to ALTER/DROP the procedures/functions as well.

I have also tried:

```
CREATE ROLE developer
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON database::MyDb TO developer
GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE::MyDb TO developer
-- Above allows modification of procedures/functions, but also tables
DENY CREATE TABLE ON DATABASE::MyDb TO developer
-- Above denies create table, can still alter/drop tables, which I also want to prevent
```

Comment: Database trigger might be the way to go.  You could have the trigger fire and if the user is a member of the correct group, you could allow it, otherwise, fail it.